# TypeError: Failed to fetch, the error I am getting, I am using reactjs as frontend and Django as backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, fetch-api

**TypeError: Failed to fetch**, the error I am getting, what I am trying to do is created a backend in Django and calling that API from reactjs but I am getting the error mentioned.

// urls.py

```
path('list', views.get_image, name='get_image'),
```

// views.py

```
def get_image(request):
pdfs = PdfStore.objects.all()
output_data = []
for i in pdfs:
    single_data = {
        "id":i.id,
        "name":i.pdf.name,
        "url":i.pdf.path
        }
    output_data.append(single_data)
return JsonResponse(output_data,safe=False)
```

// frontend-react test.js

```
get_data = async() =>{
    try{
    let body =  {
        method: 'GET',
        async: true,

    }          
    let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/list"
    let response = await fetch(url,body);
    let result = await response.json();
    console.log(result);
    } 
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Are you able to hit the endpoint in your browser to verify that it's working? Difficult to debug network requests when there are two systems talking to each other. So would be good to first know if http://127.0.0.1:8000/list shows the expected result in your browser.

Comment: i got it, i forgot to handle cors middleware in settings.py in django